# A question about using Lagrange multipliers to maximize a function

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

The function is $f(x,y,z)=13x^4+13y^4+13z^4$, and the constraint is $13x^2+13y^2+13z^2=3$.

I've set $<f_x, f_y, f_z>=\lambda<g_x, g_y, g_z>$ and got:

$$<52x^3, 52y^3, 52z^3>=\lambda<26x, 26y, 26z>$$

Then I equated everything (assuming that $x$, $y$, or $z$ are not equal to 0) to get the three equations:
$$x^2=\frac\lambda2 $$
$$y^2=\frac\lambda2$$
$$z^2=\frac\lambda2$$

After plugging these into the constraint I found
$$3\left(\frac{13\lambda}{2}\right)=3$$
so $\lambda=\frac{2}{13}$

That must mean that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all equal to $\sqrt\frac{1}{13}$

Plugging those into $f(x,y,z)$ gives $f=\left(\sqrt\frac{1}{13},\sqrt\frac{1}{13},\sqrt\frac{1}{13} \right)=\frac{3}{13}$, which should be the maximum value.
But apparently the maximum value is $\frac{9}{13}$ and $x$, $y$, and $z$ all equal $\sqrt\frac{3}{13}$ . Can someone help me figure out where I went wrong?

Comment: I think you mean $\sqrt{\frac{1}{13}}$.

Comment: Why does $f(x,y)$ have a $z$ in it?

Comment: The book answer is wrong. Put it on your constraint equation, it gives an absurd

Comment: Fixed the $f(x,y)$, thanks

Comment: @LSS, does that mean $\frac{3}{13}$ is the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

As you found, a solution (there are eight) is  $x=y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}$.

All solutions are $$(x,y,z) \in \left\{ \left(\mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{13}},\mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{13}},\mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{13}} \right)\right\}$$

$$f(x,y,z) = 13(x^4+y^4+z^4) = 13 \cdot 3\cdot \frac{1}{13^2} = \frac{3}{13}.$$

[image]

Comment: Hmm...so it seems the book answer is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, seems that way.